# Quadratics in Kinematics and the meaning of their solutions

Tags: quadratics, kinematics

I have a kinematics problem, which I can happily do using the various non-quadratic kinematics equations. But when I do it with a quadratic equation, $s = vt - \frac{1}{2}at^2$, I get two possible solutions for $t$. The issue is they are both positive and there is only one physically possible solution.

The problem is this. A particle is travelling from A to B along a straight horizontal road with constant acceleration $0.34 \text{ms}^{-2}$. At B its velocity is $20\text{ms}^{-1}$ and the distance between A and B is $400\text{m}$. Find the time taken for the car to travel from A to B. The original question gives an intermediate velocity, so this can be used to avoid the quadratic equation. However, I am very bugged by why it is the case that I get the right answer 25.5 and a wrong answer, 92.1, which can't be discerned as incorrect, from the quadratic version.

I get that if it was a negative acceleration, a deceleration, that there could be a point when the particle would return and the two physically possible values would make sense. But the acceleration is in the direction of travel and the particle will move on forever. Shouldn't the incorrect solution be negative? Or is the use of the quadratic kinematic equations not advised in certain circumstances? What is the physical meaning of the larger, incorrect answer?

My workings are as follows.

$$s=vt - \frac{1}{2}at^2$$

$$400 = 20t - \frac{1}{2}(0.34)t^2$$

$$0.17t^2 - 20t +400 = 0$$

$$t = \frac{-(-20)\pm \sqrt{20^2 - 4(0.17)(400)}}{0.34}$$

$$t = 25.5  \quad \text{and} \quad t = 92.1$$

Comment: Where did you get a negative acceleration? Your quadratic is wrong.

Comment: @JohnDouma the acceleration is not negative.

Comment: Then why do you have $-\frac{1}{2}at^2$?

Comment: Because that is the kinematics equation. A negative acceleration would contribute as a positive addition to the total. The answer to this question was the accepted "hint" below.

Comment: No, the equation of motion is $x(t) = \frac{1}{2}at^2+v_0t+x_0$ where $x$ points to the right. Since you are free to choose the origin as the starting point we can let $x_0=0$. The equation is derived starting with $\frac{dv}{dt}=a$.

Comment: @JohnDouma what you have written is a completely different kinematics equation, the quadratic with initial velocity. What I have written is a different kinematics equation, the one with final velocity. You are incorrect.

Comment: Take a look at Eddy Y's solution below. This is as easy as it gets. The $a$ has a positive coefficient.

Comment: You and Eddy Y are incorrect. This is as easy as it gets and you simply don't know of this particular kinematics equation. If you put a positive coefficient in the equation, the equation becomes incorrect. You are arguing on incomplete knowledge.

Comment: @JohnDouma A simple wikipedia could have saved you from doubling down and inadvertently admitting that your error was as simple as it gets. Equation number 5 under Constant translational acceleration in a straight line in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion.

Comment: I don't go by formulas on a web page. I derive the laws of motion using calculus and Newton's laws. The forumula $x=\frac{1}{2}at^2+v_0t+x_0$ is correct. Since initial velocity is not given, you must find it. If you had done it that way, you would have seen that there were two possible initial velocities.

Comment: This entire thread is you refusing to admit that you were wrong and now you're pretending to have known the right answer all along? You didn't even know the equation I used. When it was put beyond all reasonable doubt, you've come out with "I derive all the laws of motion which is why I didn't know about it". Yea, sure, you didn't know about it because you're too smart to know about it. Take your arrogance and insecurities elsewhere please.

Comment: If you want your equations to be clear you should say what equation you are using and what $v$ represents. This problem is easy and the way I solved it and the way Eddy solved it shows an understanding of kinematics. Eddy's only mistake was to not consider the second solution of the quadratic. If you look closely, you will see that his quadratic is the same as yours. You just looked up a formula. That takes zero understanding of the problem.

Comment: I didn't look up a formula. I know the formulae. I only had to look it up because you don't know the formula. You're now claiming that you derive the very basic kinematics equations every time you use them, something nobody would have to do. You've embarrassed yourself and are now trying to claw back the pretence that you're really very smart. Eddy's answer doesn't answer the question. He just derived my equation from another one. And now you're pretending that you didn't start off by misunderstanding what was happening all along. Intelligent people don't get this desperate when they're wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Your impression that "there is only one physically possible solution" is wrong. Try working out the initial velocity $u$ for both values of $t$ and compare their signs.

Comment: hints should posted as comments

Comment: The other comment aside, this is the answer. There is of course a scenario where the particle has initial velocity in the direction opposite to the acceleration and takes the longer time to reach B after reversing its direction. Good shout.

Answer (score 1):

The equation setup is wrong. From what I understand, the formula $s=vt-\frac{1}{2}at^2$ is used in projectile motion. This is used in the $y-$direction. If you are throwing an object, and your object is going against gravity, hence the negative acceleration (due to gravity), ie. $-a$. You can take a look on "projectile motion" on wiki for your own understanding.

You should consider the fundamental equations of motion.
$$
\begin{align}
v & = v_0 + at\\
x & = x_0+v_0t+ \frac{1}{2}at^2
\end{align}
$$
for $v_0$ and $x_0$ are your initial velocity and displacement respectively.

Now we have your above info, to find the time taken to travel $x=400m$, we do the basic substitution:

$$
\begin{align}
v & = v_0 + at \\
v_0 & = v - at \\
\end{align}
$$
We do the following algebraic substitution:
$$
\begin{align}
x & = x_0 + v_0t + \frac{1}{2}at^2 \\
& = x_0+(v-at)t+ \frac{1}{2}at^2 \\
\end{align}
$$

We substitute the values as per above:
$$
\begin{align}
400 & = 0 + (20-0.34t)t + \frac{1}{2}(0.34)t^2 \\
& = 20t - 0.17t^2 \\
\end{align}
$$
Coincidentally, we do arrive to the equation as your setup above.

Now we graph $x(t) = 20t - 0.17t^2$ for $x \in [0,400m]$ on Desmos.
[image]

Hence, when you solve your quadratic equation, the only valid solution is $t = 25.55s$.

Hope it clears your doubts.

Comment: It's no coincidence you ended up with the same equation as my setup, that equation is derived from doing exactly what you did. My setup uses u for initial velocity and v for final.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Then, the bottom points should be relevant to you then! Hopefully it helps. 
(PS: Please do vote-up my post if you think its good enough.)

Comment: I just expected a quadratic to always give a negative if there was no return journey possible. Because that quadratic seems to say that there is a return journey. When the plot you showed continues, it will turn and come back through 400 at the other value of t. Obviously, we pick the one where it passes first time... but why the return in the mathematics if there's no return in the physics! It's still bugging me lol Thanks btw, should have started with that.

Comment: No, there is no return journey. It is travelling in the positive $x$ direction. The displacement - time graph only shows the displacement $x$ (or $s$ in your case) from its initial/reference point $x=0$, starting at $t=0$. As your question states it travels for $400m$ from A to B, you find the time taken to travel for that displacement. If you really meant 'return journey'/reversing, you will see your graph going in a negative $x$ direction.

It all depends on the question, and how you setup the equation. Try not too deviate too much. Practice makes perfect.

Comment: @LostInHilbertSpace The answer is correct , but note that there is actually a second solution, with $t$ negative: that's the time at which the particle was on $B$ previously. It went from $B$ to $A$, decelerating, then reversed its direction, then went to $A$ then $B$. This is not how the experince is settled, but the physical possibility is still there.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni You don't get a negative time. You get the same solutions that LostInHilbertSpace gets. This is the correct way to do the problem. The conclusion is wrong because $92.1$ is also a solution because, as discussed above, the initial velocity could be moving away from $B$.

Answer (score 0):

The issue taken with the original solution seems to be confusion over "labeling" and  interpretation.  The problem as stated *appears to be* that the object starts at point $ \ A \ $ [position $ \ s_A \ = \ 0 \ ] \ $ with some initial velocity $ \ v_0 \ $ and travels along a straight path with a constant acceleration $ \ a \ = \ 0.34 \  \frac{\text{m}}{\text{sec}^2} \ \ , $ reaching the point $ \ B \ $ [position $ \ s_B \ = \ 400 \ ] \ $ with velocity $ \ v_B \ = \ 20 \ \frac{\text{m}}{\text{sec}} \ \ . $  The fact that the acceleration has no indicated sign is generally taken to mean that it is the *same* direction as distance is being measured, so the problem is stating that the speed of the object is *increasing* as it travels from $ \ A \ $ to $ \ B \ \ . $  The kinematic equation for distance traveled, explicitly showing time, would be
$ \ s_B - s_A \ = \ v_0·t \ + \ \frac12a·t^2 \ \ . \ $  There is of course a (temporary) difficulty in applying this, in that the initial velocity at $ \ A \ $ is not given.  We can eliminate the need to know it by using the constant-acceleration velocity equation $ \ v_B - v_0 \ = \ a·t \ $ and inserting this into the distance equation, thus
$$ 20 \ - \ v_0 \ \ = \ \ 0.34·T \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ v_0 \ \ = \ \ 20 \ - \  0.34·T $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ 400 \ - \ 0 \ \ = \ \ (20 \ - \  0.34·T)·T \ + \ \frac12·0.34·T^2 \ \ . \ $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ 400 \ \ = \ \ 20·T \ - \ \frac12·0.34·T^2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 0.17·T^2 \ - \ 20·T \ + \ 400 \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ . $$
This is the calculation **Eddy Y** makes, but the graph cropping is misleading, because there *are* two solutions for $ \ T \ $ in this kinematic equation, and they *are*
$$ \ T \ = \ \frac{20 \ \pm \ \sqrt{400 \ - \ 4·0.17·400}}{2·0.17} \ \ \approx \ \ 58.82 \ \pm \ 33.28 \ \ \approx \ \ 25.54 \ \ , \ \ 92.10 \ \ .   $$
[The curve for distance traveled being "concave downward" should have been concerning.  A more complete graph is shown here. This *should* be identified as a graph of "times at which a distance $ \ s \ $ from $ \ A \ $ is reached"; it is *not* depicting the trajectory followed by the object. ]

[image]

The first solution is (probably) the one that the problem-poser was looking for, which is the time it takes the object to leave $ \ A \ $ with velocity $ \ v_0 \ = \ 20 \ - \ 0.34·25.54 \ \approx \ 11.32 \ \frac{\text{m}}{\text{sec}} \ $ and *increase* speed at $ \ +0.34 \ \frac{\text{m}}{\text{sec}^2} \ $ toward $ \ B \ $ to arrive at $ \ B \ $ still traveling in the same initial direction $ \ 400 \ $ meters down the "road" with a speed of
$ \ 20 \ \frac{\text{m}}{\text{sec}} \ \ . $

So what about the *other* solution for $  \ T \ $ ?  If we return to the velocity equation, we obtain $ \ v_0' \ = \ 20 \ - \ 0.34·92.1 \ \approx \ -11.31 \ \frac{\text{m}}{\text{sec}} \ \ . \ $  So this represents the situation in which the object leaves $ \ A \ $ with speed $ \ \approx \ 11.32 \ \frac{\text{m}}{\text{sec}} \ $ headed *away* from $ \ B \ $ but with its acceleration of $ \ +0.34 \ \frac{\text{m}}{\text{sec}^2} \ $ toward $ \ B \  \ ; \ $ the object comes to rest momentarily after $ \ \approx \ 33.2 \ $ seconds at $ \ \approx \ 188 \ $ meters "behind" $ \ A \ \ , \ $ then increases speed *toward* $ \ B \ \ , \ $ passing $ \ A \ \ \approx \ 66.5 \ $ seconds after it started, and  reaching $ \ B \ $ traveling in the direction *opposite* to its *initial* velocity and now $ \ 400 \ $ meters down the "road" from $ \ A \ $ with a speed of $ \ 20 \ \frac{\text{m}}{\text{sec}} \ \ . $  The graph of these two trajectories is shown below.  (Note that the slopes of the curves at $ \ s \ = \ 400 \ $ are the same,  and the slope of the shorter path at $ \ s \ = \ 0 \ $ and of the "return" to $ \ s \ = \ 0 \ $ for the longer path are the same.)

[image]

So what's "wrong" with **LostInHilbertSpace**'s solution?  Actually, nothing:  the difference is in the choice of "labeling".  In writing $ \ s \ = \ vt \ - \ \frac12 at^2 \ \ , \ $ and inserting $ \ s \ = \ 400 \ $ meters, $ \ v \ = \ 20 \ $ and using a "negative" acceleration term, **LIHS** is in a sense making a "time-reversed" calculation.  The corresponding velocity equation is $ \ v_0 - v_B \ = \ -at \ \rightarrow \ v_0 \ = \ 20 \ - \ 0.34·T \ \ , \ $ which is just the same at we used above.  It may be thought of as $ \ v_0 - v_B \ = \ a·(-t) \ \ , \ $ so that we are now counting seconds *before* the object arrives at $ \ B \ $ with speed $ \ 20 \ \frac{\text{m}}{\text{sec}} \ \   $  and velocity pointed from $ \ A \ $ towards $ \ B \ \ . \ $

In **LIHS**' version of the calculation then, the question would be interpreted as: "If an object with an acceleration of $ \ 0.34   \ \frac{\text{m}}{\text{sec}^2} \ $ directed from $ \ A \ $ to $ \ B \ $ is traveling at $ \ 20 \ \frac{\text{m}}{\text{sec} } \ $ in the direction from $ \ A \ $ to $ \ B \ $ when it reaches $ \ B \ \ , \ $ and $ \ A \ $ is $ \ 400 \ $ meters away, *how long ago* was the object at $ \ A \ $ ? " The rest of their computation proceeds as above, and we understand the results as

• the object departed $ \ A \ $ about $ \ 25.5 \ $ seconds earlier heading *toward* $ \ B \ $ with a speed of $ \ 11.3 \  \frac{\text{m}}{\text{sec} } \ \ ; \ \ $ or

• the object departed $ \ A \ $ about $ \ 92.1 \ $ seconds earlier heading *away from* $ \ B \ $ with a speed of $ \ 11.3 \  \frac{\text{m}}{\text{sec} } \ \ , \ $ came to rest, reversed direction, and passed $ \ A \ $ again on its way to $ \ B \ \ . \ $

(Again, the graph here is of "time elapsed" and is *not* a graph of trajectories.)

[image]

The trajectories would look similar to those shown on the previous graphs, but now "time-reversed", with $  \ t \ = \ 0 \ $ being the moment the object reaches $ \ B \ \ . \ $   (Here, it becomes clearer that, in a sense, both trajectories are the "*same* trajectory".)

[image]

Both approaches in solving the problem are acceptable, but they indicate the degree of caution that must be exercised in applying mathematical functions (and interpreting results of calculations) to assess physical situations.  (This doesn't get any better in more advanced physics.)